# SQL 2005 Named Pipes Stop Responding

Tags: sql-server-2005, named-pipes

We have a SQL 2005 64bit SP2 server running on Windows 2003 R2 SP2. It also has Reporting Server installed and that serves as it's primary function.

Over the course of approximately a week, connecting from SSMS via named pipes gets increasingly slower until a point is reached where SSMS won't connect at all, throwing the ever-popular "Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server".

At this point, connecting via TCP/IP is still functional and incredibly fast, but SQL jobs are failing (this is my primary concern) and users can't connect via SSMS unless they change how they're connecting (less of a worry).

I have never in all my years working on SQL seen an issue such as this. There server in no way appears to be strained/over-worked (16 cores, 16GB of RAM, 12GB dedicated solely to SQL)...named pipes just gets increasingly slower until it dies.

I'm hoping that someone out there has run into this before and figured out a way to solve their issue. Or perhaps someone has some interesting way to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to update to SP4 for SQL 2005?

Comment: My first preference is to understand as much as I can about the problem. Even if the answer isn't know, can anyone out there recommend some tools you think would be useful to diagnose the issue? To answer your question more directly, it is possible, but I have another server configured in exactly the same manner that does far more work and doesn't experience this issue; it would not be the first thing I would try.